# Asp.net: Variable image source for different screen resolution

Tags: html, asp.net, image, optimization, bandwidth

Is there a way to select a different image source for different screen resolutions?

Like media queries but for only images

```
<img src="@<variable source for variable screen res.>@" />
```

to save some server bandwidth and to increase loading times for mobiles or small screens.

I have a 1800x900 image for HD screen and need to select a 900x300 version for another screen.

For those big background images within sliders, causing too much server load and time and money.

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Comment: Thanks but is there anything that is not a third-part solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using HTML:

(Source: http://css-tricks.com/on-responsive-images/)

```
<picture alt="description of image">

  <!-- low-res, default -->
  <source src="small.jpg">

  <!-- med-res -->
  <source src="medium.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">

  <!-- high-res -->
  <source src="large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">

  <!-- Fallback content -->
  <img src="small.jpg" alt="description of image">

</picture>
```

This is a pretty new and experimental feature of HTML 5, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture

### Using JavaScript:

There are couple of plugins that could solve the problem:

- [PictureFill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)
- [jQueryPicture](http://jquerypicture.com/)
- [Foresight.Js](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js)

### Using CSS:

With `<div id="picture"></div>` as a replacement to the `IMG` element:

```
#picture {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
   #picture { background-image: url('small.jpg'); width: (SMALL_WIDTH); height: (SMALL_HEIGHT); }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   #picture { background-image: url('medium.jpg'); width: (MEDIUM_WIDTH); height: (MEDIUM_HEIGHT); }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
   #picture { background-image: url('large.jpg'); width: (LARGE_WIDTH); height: (LARGE_HEIGHT); }
}
```

### Using Server-Side Solutions:

- http://squeezr.it/ (PHP)
- http://adaptive-images.com/ (PHP)